# HTML Agility Pack Performance - Load (file) versus LoadHTML (stream)

Tags: performance, html-agility-pack

Thanks to the help of a lot of folks on this site I got my screen scraping project code written and into test mode right now. It seems to be taking quite a bit of time to process the html requests. So right now I am taking the raw html stream and putting it into a string variable and passing that into the screen scraping processing code using the LoadHTML() method.

My question is this, is it faster to this or is it faster to save the html stream to a file, then parse the file?

I thought the stream would be faster but now I am not sure.

Comment: note that for loading from web url you must use new HtmlWeb().Load(url) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542955/184572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading directly from the original stream should be fastest.
If you really care, you need to measure it.