# HtmlAgilityPACK showing Error " The given path's format is not supported" when loading html page from web server

Tags: c#, web-services, web-applications, html-agility-pack

I am using my local Apache Server and its address is 127.0.0.1 . and i trying to load html page from this server to C# programme using   HTML Agility PACk   but its showing

> **ERROR : The given path's format is not supported.**

```
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        docHtml.Load(@"htttp://127.0.0.1/2.htm"); // <---  error pointer showing here 

        foreach(HtmlNode link in docHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))

        {  link.Attributes.Append("class","personal_info");


        }
        docHtml.Save("testHTML.html");


    }
```

Thank You very Much  @Slaks   after your suggesion  i Changed my COde  and its working Fine

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb docHFile = new HtmlWeb();

        docHtml = docHFile.Load("http://127.0.0.1/2.html");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`doc.Load` takes a path to a local file on disk.

You should use the `HtmlWeb` class:

```
HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked great.  I've now added a node using HTML agility pack.  How do I save back to the same non-local file?  doc.Save(Path) throws the same "path's format is not supported" error.

Comment: @boilers222: You cannot access the filesystem of another computer. You need to send an HTTP request to some server-side code that will write a file for you.