# How do I use Html Agility Pack to save a file?

Tags: c#, html, web-applications, html-agility-pack

I need to read an html file, add a tag, and save it back to the save place.  I've been able to use Html Agility Pack to read in the file and add the new tag, but I can't get save to work.  It returns the error "The given path's format is not supported."  I had the same problem with loading and I used the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542949/htmlagilitypack-showing-error-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported-when-l) to use HtmlWeb().Load instead.  I'm guessing there's a similar method for doing with with save, but I can't find it.  Can someone explain how to do this?

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        var oldPath = "https://www.myproject.com/articles/";
        var oldHtml = txtOldHtml.Text;
        var oldCompleteURL = oldPath + oldHtml;
        //doc.Load( oldCompleteURL); // Threw error "The given path's format is not supported."
        doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(oldCompleteURL);
        var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
        HtmlNode oldChild = htmlBody.ChildNodes[1];
        HtmlNode newChild = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url = " + link + ">");
        htmlBody.AppendChild(newChild);
        doc.Save( oldPath + "test.html");
```

[image]

The server is the same for both the application I'm running this update function from and the place I'm writing too, but the place I'm writing too is a level up from the application (not my decision and can't be changed).  If you have a suggestion on how to use load and save to reference a local path instead of supplying the full URL, let me know.

Application running the code above:

- Path, C:/MyProject/CMS/
- URL, www.myproject.com/CMS

Location of the HTML file I'm trying to edit:

- Path C:/MyProject/articles/article1.html
- URL, www.myproject.com/articles/article1.html

Comment: In the code you've shown `oldPath` is `https://www.myproject.com/articles/` so of course you can't save to a URL. What happens if you pass it an actual local path?

Comment: On my local machine, I can hard code the path and save on my hard drive: doc.Save("C:\\Temp\\test.html");  I haven't tried it yet on the server.  I'd like to save to www.myproject/articles/test.html (for example).

Comment: The real path to `test.html` will be something like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\articles\test.html`, you must save using this path. You can't use the URL.